# Btsync: only three of five shares synced

Tags: windows-7, linux, sync

I try to sync 5 shares from a Win7 computer to a linux box. The Linux box is configured by the following config. I experimented quite a bit with the settings but I only can get 3 of five shares synced. Can anybody tell me what is my fault? Is there a maximum number of shares in btsync?

To be completely sure that I didn't miss a detail I paste the complete config. Things I changed from the original settings are marked as :

```
{   

"device_name": "MySync",
  "listening_port" : 0,                       // 0 - randomize port

/* storage_path dir contains auxilliary app files
   if no storage_path field: .sync dir created in the directory 
   where binary is located.
   otherwise user-defined directory will be used 
*/
//  "storage_path" : "/home/user/.sync",

// uncomment next line if you want to set location of pid file
 "pid_file" : "<Userhomedir>.sync/btsync.pid",


  "check_for_updates" : true, 
  "use_upnp" : false,                              // use UPnP for port mapping


/* limits in kB/s
   0 - no limit
*/
  "download_limit" : 0,                       
  "upload_limit" : 0, 

/* remove "listen" field to disable WebUI
   remove "login" and "password" fields to disable credentials check
*/
  "webui" :
  {
/* directory_root path defines where the WebUI Folder browser starts
   (linux only)
*/
// "directory_root" : "/home/user/MySharedFolders/"
  }

/* !!! if you set shared folders in config file WebUI will be DISABLED !!!
   shared directories specified in config file
   override the folders previously added from WebUI.
*/
  ,
  "shared_folders" :
  [
    {    //Datenfass
      "secret" : "<secret1>",                   // * required field
      "dir" : "<syncfolder1>", // * required field
//  use relay server when direct connection fails
      "use_relay_server" : true,
      "use_tracker" : true, 
      "use_dht" : false,
      "search_lan" : true,
//  enable SyncArchive to store files deleted on remote devices
      "use_sync_trash" : true ,
//  restore modified files to original version, ONLY for Read-Only folders
//    "overwrite_changes" : false, 
//  specify hosts to attempt connection without additional search     
      "known_hosts" :
      [
        "<myip>:8888"
      ]
    }
,   
    {  //Compendium
      "secret" : "<secret2>",                   // * required field
      "dir" : "<sharedir2>", // * required field
//  use relay server when direct connection fails
      "use_relay_server" : true,
      "use_tracker" : true, 
      "use_dht" : false,
      "search_lan" : true,
//  enable SyncArchive to store files deleted on remote devices
      "use_sync_trash" : true,
//  restore modified files to original version, ONLY for Read-Only folders
//    "overwrite_changes" : false, 
//  specify hosts to attempt connection without additional search     
      "known_hosts" :
      [
        "<myip>:8888"
      ]
    }
,
    {     //TaggtoolDatabase
      "secret" : "<secret3>",                   // * required field
      "dir" : "<sharedir3>", // * required field
//  use relay server when direct connection fails
      "use_relay_server" : true,
      "use_tracker" : true, 
      "use_dht" : false,
      "search_lan" : true,
//  enable SyncArchive to store files deleted on remote devices
      "use_sync_trash" : true,
//  restore modified files to original version, ONLY for Read-Only folders
//    "overwrite_changes" : false, 
//  specify hosts to attempt connection without additional search     
      "known_hosts" :
      [
        "<myip>:8888"
      ]
    }
,
    { //MyInfo
      "secret" : "<secret4>",                   // * required field
      "dir" : "<sharedir4>", // * required field
//  use relay server when direct connection fails
      "use_relay_server" : true,
      "use_tracker" : true, 
      "use_dht" : false,
      "search_lan" : true,
//  enable SyncArchive to store files deleted on remote devices
      "use_sync_trash" : true,
//  restore modified files to original version, ONLY for Read-Only folders
//    "overwrite_changes" : false, 
//  specify hosts to attempt connection without additional search     
      "known_hosts" :
      [
        "<myip>:8888"
      ]
    }
,
    {//TAggToolC-Platte
      "secret" : "<secret5>",                   // * required field
      "dir" : "<sharedir5>", // * required field
//  use relay server when direct connection fails
      "use_relay_server" : true,
      "use_tracker" : true, 
      "use_dht" : false,
      "search_lan" : true,
//  enable SyncArchive to store files deleted on remote devices
      "use_sync_trash" : true,
//  restore modified files to original version, ONLY for Read-Only folders
//    "overwrite_changes" : false, 
//  specify hosts to attempt connection without additional search     
      "known_hosts" :
      [
        "<myip>:8888"
      ]
    }
  ]


// Advanced preferences can be added to config file.
// Info is available in BitTorrent Sync User Guide.

}
```

I tried to delete the folders from the Win interface, remove .SyncID and the like on the LinuxBox, adding it again on the WinBox using the interface and changing the secret to the recent one. I cannot find any .! files (which is very difficult to do in nested folders; I tried `find . -name ".\!*"`; I'm not 100% sure that works). All hints really appreciated.

btsync version on both devices is 1.3.106. The linux version is a 64 bit version.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with this setup. After waiting another day the windows client showed those shares. They already had been synchronized at that point of time.